# Unit test with Moq returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when calling method Base.GetAsync()

Tags: json, api, .net-core

I am trying to do a unit test with Moq for this method:

```
public class XsService : EntityResourceService<XModel, string>, IXResourceService<XModel, string>
{
private readonly IXsEntityRepository<XModel, string> XEntityRepository;
Public XsService(
iCorrelationContextAccessor correlationContextAccessor,
IJsonApiContext jsonApiContext,
IXsEntityRepository<XModel, string> XEntityRepository) : 
base(jsonApiContext,   XEntityRepository)
{
this.XEntityRepository = XEntityRepository;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<XModel>> GetXsAsync(UModel uModel)
{
await XEntityRepository.GetAllAsync(uModel.UserId);
return await base.GetAsync(); 
}
}
```

This is my unit test:

```
var uModels = new List<UModel>()
{
new UModel { Id = "12341", Name="group_name1" },
new UModel { Id = "12342", Name="group_name1" }
};

[Fact]
public async Task GetUAsync_Ok()
{
//Mocking base class
var baseClassMock = new Mock<XsService>(correlationContextAccessor, 
JsonApiContextMock.Object, userGroupsEntityRepositoryMock.Object) { CallBase = true };
baseClassMock.Setup(x => x.GetAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(uModels));

// Act            
var res = baseClassMock.Object.GetXsAsync(parameter);

// Assert
Assert.Equal("", "");
}
```

the Error is thrown when reaching the line:

> return await base.GetAsync();

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source=JsonApiDotNetCore StackTrace: at JsonApiDotNetCore.Services.EntityResourceService`3.GetAsyncd__8.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> JsonApiDotNetCore.Services.EntityResourceServiceTResource, TEntity,
> TId.GetAsync()
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

Maybe I need to moq EntityResourceService, like this:

```
var eRS = new Mock<EntityResourceService<UModel, string>>(jsonApiContextMock.Object, 
userGroupsEntityRepositoryMock.Object, null);
eRS.Setup(x => x.GetAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(userGroupModels));
      
var x = eRS.Object.GetAsync();
```

But, how can I inject that into the moq when creating the class instance?

This is the GetAsync method code

```
// MyModelService.cs
public class MyModelService : IResourceService<MyModel>
{
private readonly IMyModelDao _dao;

public MyModelService(IMyModelDao dao)
{ 
    _dao = dao;
} 

public Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> GetAsync()
{
    return await _dao.GetModelAsync();
}

}
```

Comment: If you testing logic of `GetAsync` of base class, please share the code. If not - why you don't want mock entire `XService` as `IXResourceService<XModel, string>`?

Comment: Hello @SergeyNazarov, I attached the code, this is base on https://json-api-dotnet.github.io/#/resource-services